# systemd service: wait for VirtualBox host mount

Tags: virtualbox, systemd, services

I have a service set on a VirtualBox VM that needs the host share to be mounted.

Here is what I have tried: I have tried each of the preconditions one at a time -- and all together as I have posted here.

```
[Unit]
Description=monitor network
Wants=network-online.target
After=network-online.target
RequiresMountsFor=/media/sf_asus

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/net.monitor.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It is not working.

The service status `systemctl status myservice` complains that the service script cannot find a required file on the host drive. However by the time the desktop has loaded, the drive has mounted and the file is available.

The script watches for changes in the network routing so to trigger the script I need to effect a change so

When I then issue :

```
 netplan apply
```

...to force a routing reset, the service works as expected.

If I then `systemctl restart` the service, it starts without complaint.

So it seems to me that these preconditions in the service definition  are either incorrect, ineffective in this context (VM), or they are poorly placed.

How can I get this to work?